# /etc/sudoers: why is there an entry for root?

Tags: sudo, root

We are distributing a standard `sudoers` file to our Linux servers.

From an historical point of view the line ..

```
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

has been removed or never added. The package default sudoers contains this line and some applications seem to require this line to work properly.

I need to argument with my team why this line needs to be present but I cannot really find an answer since root can do anything anyway.

So why is this line present ?
does it really have a functionality/purpose ?

Comment: "does it really have a functionality/purpose ?" Uh, didn't you give the answer? "some applications seem to require this line to work properly." Unless you can fix these applications or don't need them, why do you need to argue for this line at all?

Comment: the argumentation is that every change needs to have a reason. Security is a concern as well. Do we grant more privileges ? or possibilities ?

Comment: What defences do you have against sudoers being modified by root? That's to say, have your team considered that somebody who's root could simply add this line to sudoers?

Answer (score 6):

It allows you to do something like `sudo -u nobody some command...` as root, similarly to `pam_rootok.so` allows you to use `su` as root.

(Though there may be some issues with using `su` to drop privileges, see [Don't abuse su for dropping user privileges](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/dont-abuse-su-for-dropping-privileges.html).)